# JGit error when cloning repository

Tags: java, git, exception, directory, jgit

**Bug that won't fix. It's embedded into how different operating systems allows characters in file names. Solution cannot be found within JGit or Git at the moment.**

When I try to run Git.cloneRepository() I get the error that the syntax for the file-, directory name or volume lable. This have started to appear all of a sudden without any change of code concerning this piece of my software.

JRE: 1.7

Code I use:

```
private void cloneCommit() throws Exception {
  try {
    File mineDir = new File(m_target, this.m_name);

    if (!mineDir.exists()) {
      mineDir.mkdir();
      mineDir.setWritable(true);
      mineDir.setExecutable(true);
    }               

    Git g = null;

    WindowCacheConfig cfg = new WindowCacheConfig();
    cfg.setPackedGitMMAP(false);
    WindowCache.reconfigure(cfg);

    g = Git.cloneRepository()
        .setURI(m_localUri)
        .setDirectory(mineDir)
        .call();

    g.reset().setRef(this.m_current.getName()).setMode(ResetType.HARD).call();

    GlobalMessages.commitPulled(this.m_i, this.m_current.getName());

    g.getRepository().close();

    m_runningThreads--;

  } catch (Exception e) {
    errorHandlingMining(e, this.m_current);
  }
}
```

Error message:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Incorrect syntax for file name, directory name or volume label
  at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:130)
  at se.lnu.cs.doris.git.GitRepository$Cloner.cloneCommit(GitRepository.java:423)
  at se.lnu.cs.doris.git.GitRepository$Cloner.guardedCloner(GitRepository.java:446)
  at se.lnu.cs.doris.git.GitRepository$Cloner.run(GitRepository.java:440)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Incorrect syntax for file name, directory name or volume label
  at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
  at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheCheckout.checkoutEntry(DirCacheCheckout.java:968)
  at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheCheckout.doCheckout(DirCacheCheckout.java:457)
  at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheCheckout.checkout(DirCacheCheckout.java:391)
  at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.checkout(CloneCommand.java:229)
  at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:127)
  ... 4 more
```

I don't understand what the problem is. I've tried to correct it by skipping the first if-clause, just using mineDir.createNewFile() etc. The code worked superbly just a few days ago. Any suggestions?

Comment: It seem arbitrary when the error occurs. Same repository no error 30 minutes after the question was posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stack trace, the error happens in the checkout phase after the repository has been cloned. In this phase, the files and folders as recorded in the HEAD commit are created in the working directory.

So, could it be that there was a commit that introduced a file with special characters in its name? To find out, look at the history of the cloned repository.

Comment: I am guessing ' would count as a special character. Any ideas on how this can be managed? This explains the root of the problem, but sadly does not get me much closer to a solution. (And I would upvote if I could)

Comment: Is it a `'` or a `"`? According to [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions), `"` is not valid but there's no mention of `'`. On other file systems (ext4 on Linux) both are allowed, but that does not mean that it's a good idea to use it in a file name. As for a solution, I don't know what your code does, but maybe checking out is not necessary – perform the analysis or whatever on the Git repository data instead of the working directory. Or checkout to a different file system.

Comment: It is a single quote. It's a repository mining tool I've constructed. And since the problem is within JGit I assume I should just create a bug report of it and hope the producers of it can think of a genius solution. I'm not near good enough with Java to attempt to correct it myself.

Comment: I am one of the JGit developers, I don't think there is a solution. It would be interesting to see how [Git for Windows](http://git-scm.com/download/win) behaves in that case, could you try that out?

Comment: Git bash: Error: unable to create file <file name> (Invalid argument)

GitHub tool: ***Illegal characters in path!***.